# Mongo find documents sorted according to a list from another collection

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Lets say that I have the following schema:

Book

- id
- name

Customer

- id
- name

Rent

- book_id
- customer_id
- rentedAt

I want to get a list of the books a customer has rented, **sorted by the rent date**. The dumb way of doing this is to get a sorted list of rents and then perform one 'find' for every book in this list.

There must be a better way, probably using a single query. Feel free to propose schema changes, like embedding an array of "Rent" in Book or Customer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Mongoose's support for reference [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to do this efficiently:

```js
Rent.find({customer_id: custid})
    .sort({rentedAt: 1})
    .populate('book_id')
    .exec(function(err, rents) {
        // The book_id property of each rents doc contains its referenced book doc.
    });
```

Mongoose will do the Rent query first and then follow that up with a second query to get all the referenced books.

Make sure that your `Rent` schema defines `book_id` as a proper reference, as in:

```js
book_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Book' }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I am going to sleep like a baby now! Thanks